# Set alert 2 days before the start date

Tags: apex, date

I have a requirement where I need to set  alert for 2 days before start date on my object.

E.g: if the start_date__c on my object is 2/7/2016 I should have this alert as banner from 2/5/2016. I'm not sure on how to handle this.

**Current date filter:**

```
!TODAY() + 2 >= Start_Date__c
```

This work fine for the records which has future start date but still shows alert on the passed records too.

Comment: Shouldnt this be TODAY() + 2 = Start_Date__c

Comment: nope  I want  2 days before the start date

Answer (score 1):

I guess the extra requirement is that no alert should be shown for objects with a start date in the past?

How about:

```
!(TODAY() + 2 >= Start_Date__c) && (TODAY() <= Start_Date__c)
```